# return statement not working in JavaScript w/Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My Angular code does not work when written as follows:
Here it is:

```
app.directive("strength", function() {
return 
{
    require: "superhero",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, superheroCtrl) {
        superheroCtrl.addStrength();
    }
  }
})
```

**However, when the return object's first curly bracket is on the same line as the return statement, the code works:**
***Here's the code that works.***

```
app.directive("strength", function() {
    return {
        require: "superhero",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, superheroCtrl) {
            superheroCtrl.addStrength();
        }
    }
})
```

Am I doing something else incorrect?
 How else can this be solved?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you added the javascript file to your page?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Automatic_semicolon_insertion

Comment: Yes. The JS file is between <script> tags in the html and I have also added the angular src

Comment: Thanks @PSL . So the answer is: a semicolon is automatically inserted after the return statement if there is nothing else on the same line.

Comment: @raneshu yes more precisely `The return statement is affected by automatic semicolon insertion (ASI). There is no line terminator between the return keyword and the expression allowed.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to the syntax. In the first case, it causes **[automatic semicolumn insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion)** right after the `return` statement, and the second statement of defining an object literal with key/value just becomes a syntax error unless it is assigned to.

So your statement is equivalent to:-

```
return; //<-- Statement terminated here
 {
    require: "superhero", //<-- this will be a syntax error
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, superheroCtrl) {
        superheroCtrl.addStrength();
    }
  };
```

> The return statement is affected by automatic semicolon insertion (ASI). There is no line terminator between the return keyword and the expression allowed.